# Squares as a Class

Tags: c++

This program declares the Square class and uses member functions to find the perimeter and area of the square

**I didn't figure out what's wrong.  I think did most of it right.
Please input  the length of the side of the square
8
The area  of the square is 81
The perimeter of the square is 36**

```
// This program declares the Square class and uses member functions to find
// the perimeter and area of the square
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

// FILL IN THE CODE TO DECLARE A CLASS CALLED Square. TO DO THIS SEE
// THE IMPLEMENTATION SECTION.

class Square
{
      private:
        double Length;
      public:
        void setSide(float, double);
        double getArea(double);
        double getPerimeter(double);
};



int main()
{
    Square box;         // box is defined as an object of the Square class
    double side; // size contains the length of a side of the square 
    double Length;


    // FILL IN THE CLIENT CODE THAT WILL ASK THE USER FOR THE LENGTH OF THE SIDE 
    // OF THE SQUARE. (This is stored in size)
    cout << "What is the Length of the side of the square?"<<endl;
    cin >> Length;

    // FILL IN THE CODE THAT CALLS SetSide.
    box.setSide(Length, side);

    // FILL IN THE CODE THAT WILL RETURN THE AREA FROM A CALL TO A FUNCTION
    // AND PRINT OUT THE AREA TO THE SCREEN 
    cout<<"side: "<<side<<endl;
    cout << "The area is "<< box.getArea(side)<<endl;

    // FILL IN THE CODE THAT WILL RETURN THE PERIMETER FROM A CALL TO A 
    // FUNCTION AND PRINT OUT THAT VALUE TO THE SCREEN 
    cout << "The perimeter is " << box.getPerimeter(side)<<endl;
    system("pause");

    return 0;
}

//__________________________________________________________________
//Implementation section Member function implementation

//**************************************************
// setSide
//
// task: This procedure takes the length of a side and
// places it in the appropriate member data
// data in: length of a side
//***************************************************

void Square::setSide(float Length, double side)
{
   Length = side;


}

//**************************************************
// findArea
//
// task: This finds the area of a square
// data in: none (uses value of data member side)
// data returned: area of square
//***************************************************

double Square::getArea()
{
    return Length * Length

}

//**************************************************
// findPerimeter
//
// task: This finds the perimeter of a square
// data in: none (uses value of data member side)
// data returned: perimeter of square
//*************************************************** 

double Square::getPerimeter()
{
    return Length * 4; 

}
```

Comment: Did you really think that this would be an appropriate question title?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oh dear.

- `setSide` should only take one argument, and store the value in the member variable.
- `setArea` should be called `getArea` or `findArea`.  (I prefer "get", but in that case, make it `getPerimeter` too.)
- Both `getArea` and `getPerimeter` should not take any arguments (and should be const member functions).
- You should decide to use either `float` or `double` throughout.  (If in doubt, use `double`).

Answer (score 1):

The area of a square with side 8, is 64... what are you getting as output?

Please paste your actual code:

```
 cout << "The area is "<< box.setArea(side)<<endl;
```

would not compile with the code you paste (where is setArea defined)

Comment: This should be a comment instead of an answer.